# mysql search in main query and subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Having the following query where i am trying to search in a query, i might be writing a wrong syntax, but i am not sure how to correct it. I want to search for the text in the main table and the subquery table too.

here is my query

```
select mytable.*
    from mytable 
    where spam = 0 
    and deleted = 0 
    and draft = 0     
     and (subject like '%guss%' or body like '%guss%' or 
     (select CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) as fname,users.email 
      from users where firstname like '%guss%' or lastname like 'guss'))

    and id = 24
    order by id desc
```

getting this Error

```
[Err] 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Update #1

```
select mytable.*
    from mytable 
    where spam = 0 
    and deleted = 0 
    and draft = 0     
     and (subject like '%eli%' or body like '%eli%' or 
     (select users.firstname 
      from users where firstname like '%eli%') or 
     (select users.lastname 
      from users where lastname like '%eli%'))

    and id_receiver = 24
    order by id desc
```

Comment: Can you show how mytable relates to users and describe what output is expected along with sample data?

Comment: the mytable has an ID field and the users table has the ID field as PK

Comment: what should i show now, the issue is there, should i use union

Comment: What rows/columns do you want in expected results just values from "myTable" where sapm = 0 deleted = 0 draft = 0 and subject or body contain 'eli' or first/last name is eli and the recceiver is 24?

Comment: Where did the email field go?  Is it wanted in the output or what?

Answer (score 0):

Here the error:

```
(select CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) as fname,users.email 
  from users where firstname like '%guss%' or lastname like 'guss'))
```

In your subquery you can return only one column

This is the first column: `CONCAT(users.firstname,' ', users.lastname) as fname`

This is the second column: `users.email`

Comment: While I agree with this I also struggle with the fact it's in a where clause on an OR statement that has no associated condition to compare against.  So I believe there's a compound error here.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it does not return results, if i run it single query, it do return results. Check Update #1 in main Question

Comment: IMHO Your update goes in error. A subquery can return only a row. This (select users.firstname 
      from users where firstname like '%eli%') can return a lot of rows! Please add before your subquery an EXISTS clause

Comment: hmm, can we use join here

Answer (score 0):

You put a 2-column result as an operand of OR expression. 
This causes the issue. It should return one column or be compared to something. 
But if you want to search in both tables I guess UNION would be something you need.

Answer (score 0):

Though I think this is wrong I don't believe mytable.id relates to users.id but that's what a comment said...

```
SELECT Distinct mytable.*
FROM mytable 
INNER JOIN users
 on myTable.ID = users.Id   
WHERE mytable.spam = 0 
 and mytable.deleted = 0 
 and mytable.draft = 0     
 and CONCAT_WS(mytable.subject, mytable.body, users.firstname, users.lastname) like '%eli%'
 and mytable.id_receiver = 24
ORDER BY mytable.id desc
```

I removed the or using string concatenation.  We want any record having the text of 'eli' in any of the columns subject, body, firstname, lastname.  The system would have to loop through each column checking for a %eli% value.  In theory up to 4 loops. By adding all the columns together to form one string and checking for eli we eliminate extra looping the engine would have to do at an overhead of the string concatenation.  This should be faster.

I used distinct as I don't know what results you want and if the join will result in multiple records that serve no purpose.  Since a * is being used I couldn't use a group by properly.

I joined to users assuming that you only want records in mytable that link to a user.  This may be a wrong assumption.